# Easier way to turn deepslate/stone to cobbled deepslate/cobbled stone

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have a bunch of deepslate and stone that I want to turn into cobbled deepslate and cobbled stone. I can do this by placing it then mining it again, but it's pretty tedious and takes a long time.

Is there some way to directly turn deepslate into cobbled deepslate, and stone into cobbled stone, without placing it and mining it again? Is there a machine that can do it? I was hoping the stone cutter could do it but alas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only mechanic, besides a player wielding a pick without silk touch, that the Bedrock game has for such a conversion are (mob-induced) explosions.  Creepers, in particular.  However, this is an unreliable mechanic and is not a 100% drop rate.  Ghast explosions have a 100% drop rate (at least as of when I last watched a tutorial for making use of them as block breakers), but are too weak to break (cobble)stone and deepslate; they are otherwise the current best option for auto-breaking many blocks, like logs, in Bedrock.  Unlike in Java, TNT also does not have a 100% drop rate, nor can it be duped, making many automated breaking farms in Java non-functional in Bedrock.  But I can confirm that creeper explosions will convert stone into cobblestone, provided they succeed in breaking the stone and in dropping it (a 1/3 chance, as I understand it). Coincidentally had this happen to me just the other day.  As the stone will absorb most of the blast force, this will be a lossy conversion over a very small region, even if you go out of your way to try to maximize the number of blocks affected. Withers may be more usable, though require such a significant investment and are so risky to use for farming that it would seem silly to do this just to convert some stone to cobblestone; having them blast through existing world stone would already be simpler.

There appears to be no easy way of automating the placing or movement of blocks for you to mine.  Dispensers don't place the block, pistons pushing them into a cactus just breaks the cactus, etc. So even just trying to make a redstone contraption to enable you to mine and/or place blocks in one spot won't work that well, and would be very costly.  An array of smart pistons could be set up to create a large chunk of blocks you could then go over to and mine up, but this will need a lot of pistons (and so a lot of cobblestone), plus the time building the redstone triggers. Since you'd be manually placing the blocks initially, this seems unlikely to be better than just running back and forth doing things normally unless you have many thousands of blocks to run through and large piles of pistons sitting around.

If you need large amounts of stone or cobblestone, I would suggest simply building a farm for it. You can hold onto your existing blocks, or use them as the building blocks for said farms.  [Prowl8413 has a high speed stone generator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-jrW0IqX2rs) that I've built and would recommend, as you can get many thousands of blocks per hour just standing in place mining with it.  It is basically 4 standard stone generators compiled into one, in order to circumvent certain issues stone generators have in Bedrock.  The Bedrock mechanic for producing stone from the suitable interaction of lava and water is a little wonky, resulting in the simpler versions being slower as you must wait longer for new stone blocks to appear.  However, cobblestone (and basalt) generators work as they do in Java and in particular the blocks will eventually start generating as fast as you can mine them, resulting in much smaller and simpler builds.  Any build based on something like [1upMC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OXB5JRIzKBE)'s or [JC Playz](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SDrp-yQPE0M)'s* will let you mine a whole bunch of cobblestone very quickly, and you can easily expand them to generate the blocks up to 5-deep if you really want. They are also easily modified to produce basalt instead, if desired.

Unfortunately there are no farms for deepslate, [outside of those risking things like the Wither](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ciNWGIHNdE), as these are non-renewable resources.  Simply mining a huge hole in the earth is your best option.  An ancient city, once cleared of shriekers, is a rather pain free source of all sorts of deepslate blocks, including "cracked" versions of several blocks that you can't otherwise obtain in survival.

---

*<sub>I've found that on any of these builds some slight modifications to the initial collection system are in order to prevent losses. In my experience, sometimes blocks will pop out of the sides or tops, even through multiple layers of solid blocks, with any of these linked farms. Using one or more hopper minecarts as the first line of collection seems to be the best way to grab these blocks and not lose them. For example: my basalt generator was spitting them out of the top with just hoppers, and adding a hopper minecart under the generation spot solved that (similar to how JC Playz's cobblestone farm does it). Prowl's stone farm had a similar issue for me, and using hopper minecarts instead of hoppers directly under where the stone was being mine resolved that.  But then my basalt generator started spitting them out of the right-hand side sometimes, so I added an extra hopper minecart and hopper to the right side of the base one, and that fixed that problem.</sub>

Comment: My biggest issue is that deepslate isn't analogous to stone, i.e. once you smelt the cobbled form you are left with a useless block.  I want to smelt cobbled deepslate to get experience to mend my pickaxe which just dug the deepslate, but now i'm left with a stone which is useless to me as I can't make anything out of it.

Answer (score 0):

An auto-mine farm is probably your best bet.

ilmango has designed an [automatic industrial cobblestone generator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vsWm6F9Ggc4), but since you already have the stone, and particularly with the deepslate, you might be better off with an [automatic tree farm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p4Jg0PxGaMk) instead.

Basically, the mechanism is that TNT now drops *all* items it destroys, so you get 100% return on the items you destroy with it. The most basic design would be something like this:

[image]

You place the blocks on the detector (Black), which powers the piston (Brown) to push it along. Then an automatic/timed dispenser deploys a block of TNT (Red) onto an indestructible block (Grey), which blows up the block(s) for you to collect.

Comment: Your video and TNT mechanics are only valid in Java edition, but the OP is tagged as Bedrock.  Last I checked TNT is not a 100% breaker in Bedrock (nor can it be duped, I think), making all TNT-assisted farmers Java exclusive.  Bedrock users have Ghast blast chambers at best, but they're not strong enough for breaking (cobble)stone.

Comment: Ah good point! An oversight on my part unfortunately